# The Garry's Mod Lua an API or a language itself?

Tags: lua

Is the following documentation to an API or is it a language?

http://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/Main_Page

considering that this is an API:

http://docs.oxidemod.org/rust/#universal-hooks

I thought this might be too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lua is its own [coding language](https://www.lua.org/docs.html). GLua is an API that uses Lua; see the [GLua documentation](http://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/Main_Page) for more details. In short, yes GLua is an API.